# About the solutions of a PDE

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I would like to know how the following statement is proved. I do not have any reference, buy I want to know where this come from because it is used in a proof that I am working with and I am not familiar with PDE's. Maybe is an extension of a real PDE's result, but I do not know.

> Let $g,h:U\subset\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ be two analytic
>   functions, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ that contains
>   $z_0:=(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\subset\mathbb{C}^2$.
>
> Then, the solutions of the equation \begin{equation}
>      g(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + h(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0\end{equation} are the functions $f$ that are constant
>   on the solutions of \begin{equation}
>      \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{h}{g}. \end{equation}
>
> Moreover, such functions are determined by their values on any
>   transversal to the solutions through $z_0 := (x_0,y_0)\in
>  \mathbb{R}^2\subset\mathbb{C}^2$.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the method of characteristics. Have you read up on this?

Comment: I skimmed the method of characteristics and it seems to be quite analogous, but I can not imagine the geometry on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and this method is based on geometrical facts (the surface where the solutions lie, etc). Is there an extension of the method of characteristics for $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Answer (score 1):

If $x(z)$, $y(z)$ are the solutions of the complex ODE system
$$
\frac{dx(z)}{dz}=g(x(z),y(z))\\
\frac{dy(z)}{dz}=h(x(z),y(z))
$$
then you get as in the real case that along these characteristic curves
$$
\frac{d}{dz}f(x(z),y(z))=\frac{∂f}{∂x}(x(z),y(z))g(x,y)+\frac{∂f}{∂y}(x(z),y(z))h(x,y)=0,
$$
so that $f$ is constant along these curves.

With a parameter change for these characteristic curves you can also invert the relation of $x$ and $z$ so that $y$ is then a function of $x$.